# Click on another extension icon and read its popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have an extension click on another extension's icon and interact with the resulting popup. It seems straightforward but I haven't found anywhere that hints at how to do it.

Comment: If both extensions were developed by you then you can interact by passing messages.

Comment: The target extension wasn't developed by me.

Comment: I don't think it can be done

Comment: The only way is to use Chrome beta/dev/Canary and chrome.debugger API to attach to another extension's background script and inject chrome.browserAction.openPopup(), then attach to the popup and read its contents. Might be easier to just re-implement the whole thing.